# Sony Xperia U android resolution issues

Tags: android, drawable, resolution, screen-resolution, sony

As Sony Xperia U's resolution is 480 * 854 (280ppi) it should take images from high density folder(drawable-hdpi) but its taking images from extra high folder(drawable-xhdpi) and not scaling properly.We are not having actual device for testing so setting emulator Height=854 ,Width=480 and density=320.We have also added specific drawable-h854dp folder for xperia but it is still taking images from drawable-xhdpi and not scaling it.Has any one faced this kind of issue?Suggest us if have any ideas.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Unless you're only designing the app to only run on the Xperia U, you shouldn't do anything specific for it. There are too many different Android devices out there to write for each one. If Sony haven't implemented Android correctly then it is for them to fix it. Otherwise, the phone is doing exactly as it should. Apps will all look different on all the many screen sizes and resolutions. It is also hard to know what you mean by "not scaling properly". Is it too big or too small? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 1):

280ppi is directly between `hdpi` (240ppi) and `xhdpi` (320). Chances are, Sony has defined the Xperia U as an `xhdpi` device, so for it to take resources from `drawable-xhdpi` is completely normal. There's an app in the market I found called [Check Screen Size](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pmc.android.checkscreensize) that will tell you what density your device is defined as (and what resources it will be using).

Comment: yeah thanks for your reply.It is obvious that it will take images from drawable-xhdpi but the screen size is some what similar to devices that take images from drawable-hdpi so all the images are looking too large that come from drawable-xhdpi and fit in 480*854 screen size.Any solution that can make application's look normal?

Comment: The problem is that width of 480px is 240dp which is a lot narrower than Google's guideline of minimum 320dp width screen in an Android device.Even stock Android home screen in an emulator doesn't have enough room.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it under `drawable-w240dp` or `drawable-h427dp` or even `drawable-w240dp-h427dp` it should work.

I wouldn't bother too much since it's Sony's fault that they have not followed Android device guidelines for minimum (effective) screen size.